# Getting String Index out of Bounds in Layout Preview

Tags: android-studio

I am building a Login screen from the template of Android Studio, but the layout doesn't preview. It says:

```
Rendering Problems Exception raised during rendering: String index out of range: 0 (Details)
```

The details include:

```
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 0
    at java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:686)
    at com.android.internal.util.XmlUtils_Delegate.convertValueToInt(XmlUtils_Delegate.java:47)
    at com.android.internal.util.XmlUtils.convertValueToInt(XmlUtils.java:88)
    at android.content.res.BridgeTypedArray.getInt(BridgeTypedArray.java:204)
    at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:1051)
    at android.widget.EditText.<init>(EditText.java:65)
    at android.widget.EditText.<init>(EditText.java:61)
    at android.widget.EditText.<init>(EditText.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor237.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.onCreateView(BridgeInflater.java:93)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:682)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:741)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:138)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:806)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:64)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:782)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:809)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:64)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:782)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:809)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:64)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:782)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:809)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:64)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:782)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:385)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:413)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:321)
    at com.android.ide.common.rendering.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:350)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$2.compute(RenderTask.java:510)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$2.compute(RenderTask.java:498)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:888)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:498)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.access$600(RenderTask.java:72)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$3.call(RenderTask.java:610)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$3.call(RenderTask.java:607)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderService.runRenderAction(RenderService.java:366)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.render(RenderTask.java:607)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.render(RenderTask.java:629)
    at com.intellij.android.designer.designSurface.AndroidDesignerEditorPanel$6.run(AndroidDesignerEditorPanel.java:480)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:320)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:310)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue$2.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:254)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:269)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:227)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:217)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.QueueProcessor.runSafely(QueueProcessor.java:238)
    at com.intellij.util.Alarm$Request$1.run(Alarm.java:351)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:439)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:695)
```

Looks like a problem with some EditText in the code. I have two of them One is for the username and second is for the password.

Here's my XML code for the layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".LoginActivity">

    <!-- Login progress -->

    <ProgressBar android:id="@+id/login_progress" style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp" android:visibility="gone" />

    <ScrollView android:id="@+id/login_form" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">



        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/email_login_form" android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:src="@drawable/hs_logo" />

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <EditText android:id="@+id/email" android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:hint="Username"
                    android:imeActionId="@+id/login"
                    android:imeActionLabel="@string/action_sign_in_short"
                    android:imeOptions="actionUnspecified" android:inputType="text"
                    android:maxLines="1" android:singleLine="true" />

            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <EditText android:id="@+id/password" android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:hint="@string/prompt_password"
                    android:imeActionId="@+id/login"
                    android:imeActionLabel="@string/action_sign_in_short"
                    android:imeOptions="actionUnspecified" android:inputType="textPassword"
                    android:maxLines="1" android:singleLine="true" />

            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            <Button android:id="@+id/email_sign_in_button" style="?android:textAppearanceSmall"
                android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp" android:text="@string/action_sign_in"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

It has been an hour solving this issue.

Comment: try to change the app theme in layout preview. I have this problem too but after changing the theme it works.